# Bootpag Pagination how to load page with actual data

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

```
// init bootpag
    $('#page-selection').bootpag({
        total: 2
    }).on("page", function(event, /* page number here */ num){}
```

The function works fine but on first load, nothing appears on first page. I have to click on page 2 to get actual data. I want to know if there is a function to perform the actual click on first page

Comment: Did you try to wrap it inside `$(document).ready(function(){ /*init bootpag here*/ })`? A fiddle will be helpful.

Comment: Yes I did but when I init, it says bootpag is not a function

Comment: Maybe you forgot to include the bootpag lib intro your html, or the `$('#page-selection')` selector is not valid (meaning that the element with id `page-selection` is not found); it was (and still is ) better to provide a fiddle.